# Cassandra count use case

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I'm trying to figure out an appropriate use case for Casandra's counter functionality. I thought of a situation and I was wondering if this would be feasible. I'm not quite sure because I'm still experimenting with Cassandra so any advice would be appreciated.

Lets say you had a small video service, you record the log of views in Cassandra while recording what video was played, which user played it, country, referer etc. You obviously want to show a count of how many times that video was played would incrementing a counter every time you insert a play event be a good solution to this? Or would there be a better alternative. Counting all the events on read every time would take a pretty big performance hit and even if you cached the results the cache would be invalidated pretty quickly if you had a busy site.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Counters can be used for whatever you need to count within an application -- both "frontend" data and "backend" one. I personally use them to store user's behaviour information (for backend analysis) and frontend ratings (each operation a user do in my platform give to the user some points). There is no real limitation on use case -- the limitation is given by few technical limitations, the bigger coming to my mind:

1. a counter cf can be made only by counters columns (except PK, obviously)
2. counters can't be reset: to set 0 value to a counter you need to read and calculate before writing (with no guarantee about the fact that someone else updated before you)
3. no ttl and no indexing/deletion

As far as your video service it all depends on how you choose to model data -- if you find a valid model to hit few partitions each time you write/read and you have a good key distribution I don't see any real problem in its implementation.

btw: you tagged Cassandra 2.0 but if you have to use counters you should think about 2.1 for the reasons described [here](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/whats-new-in-cassandra-2-1-a-better-implementation-of-counters)

Comment: Thanks Carlo, one last thing. Have you ever had issues with the integrity of counters. Ex. If i record a log of each event and increment the counter on writes should i be concerned about the counters value eventually being incorrect ? Should cassandra counters be used if accuracy is what I'm looking for? Also for the video use case is there any better way you know of keeping an accurate count without taking a performance hit, i really don't want to count on read because i expect to have millions of logs. Redis comes to mind?

Comment: Jesse I didn't have any issue with counters so far (I've been using it for at least 3 years) -- but I strictly followed the rules concerning counters. In Cassandra 2.1 you can tune them in order to achieve better performance. For your use case, to know the better implementation, you should provide the exact data you need to save and queries you'd like to perform (count the videos seen by a user, count how many users have seen a video and so on). I'd suggest you to do this in a new clean post concerning a data model. Regards, Carlo

Comment: Yeah i just read the article on 2.1 counters and it sounds like a major improvement. My queries are very straight forward i just want an accurate global count per item. No fancy queries. If you can answer that i would appreciate it but thanks so much for the insight Carlo.

Comment: To achieve what you need there is nothing hard to do to using counters -- what I'm telling you is I need to know queries to "organize" data. For instance if you use a different key for each video information -- for instance videoid_played and videoid_hired if in one moment you need to know how many times a video has been played and hired you need to perform 2 queries. Instead if you use a composite primary key with a wide row (video_id, operation) you can access all your data concerning a specific video with a single query. HTH, Carlo

Comment: Well i was thinking of having a composite primary key looking like ((video_id, operation), uuid). This way i could have multiple operations such as plays, likes, dislikes etc. Like i said though I'm not overly concerned about my query patterns just because the only queries ill be doing on these tables are for analytics. The only client facing data will be the count.